# Is there a way to get milliseconds to show when I call .ToString() on a DateTime WITHOUT using "fff"?

Tags: .net, datetime, datetime-format

I am pulling a DateTime value from a database that I need to store in a textbox (it's an ASP.NET TextBox if you must know).  This DateTime contains milliseconds.  I then need to save this value back to the database.

The problem:  When I do `MyTextBox.Text = dbValue.ToString()`, the milliseconds are excluded.  When the user goes to save the record, it does a `DateTime.Parse()` on the TextBox value and writes that back to the database.  Since the string no longer contains milliseconds, that component of the DateTime is lost on the save.

I am aware that I could specify the milliseconds on the way in by providing a custom format string that uses `fff`, but I am sort of wanting this to be considerate of culture.  This means I don't want to hardcode a format string since that format string could theoretically be invalid if my code is executed on a machine using different culture info.

Conceptually, I am looking for a dynamic approach where all I have to do is tell `.ToString()` to use milliseconds based on the current culture without having to provide a format string.

Comment: If you are calling `ToString` to translate it into the format expected  by your database, it doesn't matter what the culture setting is. `fff` will be milliseconds regardless of culture.

Comment: But, in order to force `fff`, I have to generate a custom format string, do I not?

Comment: Can the user edit the textbox? If the answer is no, then you shouldn't parse the text to put it in the database. You should use the DateTime value that you display in the textbox.

Comment: @JoelRondeau, Yes, the user can edit the textbox.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin Yes, you'll have a custom format string for putting it in the format required, but that won't affect the user, and unless the day of week (like 'Wednesday') is a part of what is saved in your database, I can't see how culture would matter since often the culture specific stuff really just relates to the order of things (which you'll explicitly define in the format string). Surely your database is using a consistent format?

Answer (score 1):

**I will Suggest to use a extension methods for that ...**

```
public static class Extended
    {
        public static String ToDateX(this DateTime Caller)
        {
            return Caller.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH-mm-ss-fff", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-gb"));
        }
    }
```

This may resolved your problem since it will not use application **Culture** ..

Comment: This may be an dumb question, but is it theoretically possible that not all cultures are registered on a machine?

Comment: As per my best knowledge culture are not registered in client machine ... It's dot net framework which contains all culture info and provide as requested ... Now if you wants to make your application culture independent then change the mainthread culture to your desired one on application start .... then the whole application will be in same culture....

Answer (score 1):

I know @oscilatingcretin your requirement might be fulfilled in these days .. but for sake of fresh programmer who are facing these type problems.. i am posting an answer .. which is fully `independent of Culture`

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {               
        //Cloning culture to assign
        var newCulture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;

        //Datetime.ToString() internally use 
        //Datetime.ToString(DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern+" "+ DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern)
        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "hh:mm:ss fff";
        //you can specify custom format for month tooo
        //newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MMM-yy";            

        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;

        DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```